# Moving from universal iOS app to separate iPhone/iPad apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-universal-app

I started developing a universal app because I was told to do that way as a requirement, but now I'm being asked about the possibility of switching to separate iPhone and iPad versions and I need to give an idea of the effort that making this change will have.

I've been looking for posts dealing with this issue but what I found mostly dealt with moving from separate to universal, not in reverse, so I need somebody who had to do the same to help me to make clear some questions I have:

1) Having a project target set to universal, if I simply set it to iPhone or iPad, does the build ignore all the resources the app won't need (~iPad resources if set to iPhone, and viceversa), or it will include them in the build anyway? Is it needed to remove the unnecessary resources from the target's build phases section?

2) So, should I create two more targets in addition to the universal one, or is it enough to change the device in my current target to the one I need, iPhone or iPad, and just build it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Yes, if you have not edit the build settings
2. What is the purpose of switching to separate target?

Comment: Just change the Targeted Device Family in the build settings. Or create two separate target and add resources like images to their respective target.

Comment: Remember: users can always buy the iPhone version to use on their iPad.